# GCC dump preprocessor defines

Tags: gcc, g++, c-preprocessor

Is there a way for gcc/g++ to dump its default preprocessor defines from the command line?
I mean things like `__GNUC__`, `__STDC__`, and so on.

Answer (score 391, accepted):

Yes, use [`-E`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-E) [`-dM`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-dM) options instead of [-c](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-c).
Example (outputs them to standard output):

```
 echo | gcc -dM -E -
 echo | clang -dM -E -
```

For C++

```
 echo | g++ -dM -E -x c++ -
 echo | clang++ -dM -E -x c++ -
```

From the [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-dM-908):

> Instead of the normal output, generate
> a list of `#define' directives for all
> the macros defined during the
> execution of the preprocessor,
> including predefined macros. This
> gives you a way of finding out what is
> predefined in your version of the
> preprocessor. Assuming you have no
> file foo.h, the command
>
> ```
> touch foo.h; cpp -dM foo.h
> ```
>
> will show all the predefined macros.
>
> If you use -dM without the -E option,
> -dM is interpreted as a synonym for -fdump-rtl-mach.

Comment: gcc exists on systems where /dev/null means nothing.

Comment: @Pavel then you can use an empty file, either with gcc or the preprocessor - cpp.

Comment: I added a more portable approach as an alternative answer: `echo | gcc -dM -E -` works on windows as well.

Comment: Is it possible to determine where (i.e., in which file) those defines came from?

Comment: @edam To determine source of macro, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257455/how-to-find-the-source-of-some-macros

Comment: Alternatively, on Windows, `cpp -dM -E - < NUL` can be used.

Comment: Don't forget the '-x c++' command line flag if you're printing c++ define macros. The complete command is: 'g++ -x c++ -dM -E - < /dev/null' for C++ specific macros.

Comment: One of the most useful answers, ever. I keep coming back here to get the incantation.

Comment: How do I find the list of available macros like \__FILE__ \__DATE__ \__TIMESTAMP__ etc? A few are listed in the docs [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html#Standard-Predefined-Macros) but is that it?

Comment: @EricNelson I think it is

Comment: Does armcc have a similar feature?

Comment: Note that you can add command line arguments to the command given in this answer, some may add defines which will then show up. For example, adding `-mavx2` adds the defines `#define __AVX__ 1` `#define __AVX2__ 1` on x86 architectures.

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27686382/1593077) about doing the same with NVCC for CUDA.

Comment: No need to rely on shell redirection. *nix: `gcc -dM -E /dev/null`, Windows: `gcc -dM -E nul`. Specify an input file instead of stdin.

Comment: I've tried this with a few builds of `g++`, and `__cplusplus` is never included in the output, even though the standard mandates that it be defined.

Comment: Just saw user402642's comment above. Adding -x c++ causes `__cplusplus`  to be shown in the output.

Comment: This has been working fine for me on most gcc, but MinGW's gcc 12.2.0 doesn't print anything (works, compiles, does its job, `-dumpersion` works but `-dM` doesn't).

Comment: Using `-x c++` obviates the need for switching to the `g++` and `clang++` frontends respectively (i.e. `gcc` and `clang` will also work this way). The reason is that without a file name the language cannot be deduced.

Answer (score 87):

I usually do it this way:

```
$ gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null
```

Note that some preprocessor defines are dependent on command line options - you can test these by adding the relevant options to the above command line. For example, to see which SSE3/SSE4 options are enabled by default:

```
$ gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null | grep SSE[34]
#define __SSE3__ 1
#define __SSSE3__ 1
```

and then compare this when `-msse4` is specified:

```
$ gcc -dM -E -msse4 - < /dev/null | grep SSE[34]
#define __SSE3__ 1
#define __SSE4_1__ 1
#define __SSE4_2__ 1
#define __SSSE3__ 1
```

Similarly you can see which options differ between two different sets of command line options, e.g. compare preprocessor defines for optimisation levels `-O0` (none) and `-O3` (full):

```
$ gcc -dM -E -O0 - < /dev/null > /tmp/O0.txt
$ gcc -dM -E -O3 - < /dev/null > /tmp/O3.txt
$ sdiff -s /tmp/O0.txt /tmp/O3.txt 
#define __NO_INLINE__ 1        <
                               > #define __OPTIMIZE__ 1
```

Answer (score 50):

*Late answer - I found the other answers useful - and wanted to add a bit extra.*

---

**How do I dump preprocessor macros coming from a particular header file?**

```
echo "#include <sys/socket.h>" | gcc -E -dM -
```

or (thanks to @mymedia for the suggestion):

```
gcc -E -dM -include sys/socket.h - < /dev/null
```

In particular, I wanted to see what SOMAXCONN was defined to on my system.  I know I could just open up the standard header file, but sometimes I have to search around a bit to find the header file locations.  Instead I can just use this one-liner:

```
$ gcc -E -dM -include sys/socket.h - < /dev/null | grep SOMAXCONN
#define SOMAXCONN 128
$
```

Comment: you can use [-include](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) compiler option to avoid pipes

Comment: You can specify `/dev/null` (or `nul` on Windows) as the "input file" (instead of the `-`, which means `stdin`) and not need any pipe or `<`.

Answer (score 34):

The simple approach (`gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null`) works fine for gcc but fails for g++. Recently I required a test for a C++11/C++14 feature. Recommendations for their corresponding macro names are published at https://isocpp.org/std/standing-documents/sd-6-sg10-feature-test-recommendations. But:

```
g++ -dM -E - < /dev/null | fgrep __cpp_alias_templates
```

always fails, because it *silently* invokes the C-drivers (as if invoked by `gcc`). You can see this by comparing its output against that of gcc or by adding a g++-specific command line option like (-std=c++11) which emits the error message `cc1: warning: command line option ‘-std=c++11’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C`.

Because (the non C++) gcc will **never** support "Templates Aliases" (see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2258.pdf) you must add the `-x c++` option to force the invocation of the C++ compiler (Credits for using the `-x c++` options instead of an empty dummy file go to yuyichao, see below):

```
g++ -dM -E -x c++ /dev/null | fgrep __cpp_alias_templates
```

There will be no output because g++ (revision 4.9.1, defaults to -std=gnu++98) does not enable C++11-features by default. To do so, use

```
g++ -dM -E -x c++ -std=c++11 /dev/null | fgrep __cpp_alias_templates
```

which finally yields

```
#define __cpp_alias_templates 200704
```

noting that g++ 4.9.1 does support "Templates Aliases" when invoked with `-std=c++11`.

Comment: You don't have to use a dummy file. GCC supports the `-x` argument so `g++ -x c++ -dM -E -std=c++11 - < /dev/null | grep cpp` should work.

Comment: @yuyichao Thank you, this makes it easier to use. I wasn't aware of the -x option. Upvoted your comment and integrated it into the original answer.

Answer (score 26):

A portable approach that works equally well on Linux or Windows (where there isn't any [/dev/null](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device#Usage)):

```
echo | gcc -dM -E -
```

For C++, you may use (replace `c++11` with whatever version you use):

```
echo | gcc -x c++ -std=c++11 -dM -E -
```

It works by telling GCC to preprocess [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)) (which is produced by [echo](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo)) and [print all preprocessor defines](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) (search for `-dletters`). If you want to know what defines are **added** when you include a header file, you can use the [`-dD`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-dD) option which is similar to [-dM](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-dM), but it does not include predefined macros:

```
echo "#include <stdlib.h>" | gcc -x c++ -std=c++11 -dD -E -
```

Note, however, that empty input still produces lots of defines with the `-dD` option.

Comment: @rubenvb it's irrelevant. the point is to have cmd line that works equally well on windows and unix at least. If you use `NUL`, you are back to square one: it won't work on systems that do not have it.

Comment: adding full answer for C++, works on both Windows and Linux (although `sort` behaves little different): `echo | gcc -x c++ -std=c++17 -dM -E - | sort`

Comment: This produces empty output in git-bash.

Comment: @LennartRolland does it have gcc? In my git-bash I cannot run gcc

Comment: @pavel I use mingw32 gcc that comes with Qt5 binary distribution for windows.

Comment: Don't know what to say. Mingw64 that comes with msys2 works for me: `echo | x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe -dM -E -`. Try to run it in cmd.exe to verify that it all works properly?

Answer (score 4):

While working in a big project which has complex build system and where it is hard to get (or modify) the gcc/g++ command directly there is another way to see the result of macro expansion.
Simply redefine the macro, and you will get output similiar to following:

```
file.h: note: this is the location of the previous definition
#define MACRO current_value
```

Comment: I am looking for what warning flag is used for it. Do you know ?

Comment: Maybe `-Wno-builtin-macro-redefined ` is the one?