# What is defined in Mac OS GCC for C?

Tags: macos, gcc, c-preprocessor

So I wonder where to get the list of default Mac OS GCC defines for pure C? Can any one post list here?

Why I need such thing:

I do not have mac OS X, I try to compile ffmpeg with alchemy GCC under ubuntu, and ffmpeg wonders which os it is. And gives me wornings like

```
                from libavformat/os_support.c:28:
/home/rupert/Desktop/arch/alchemy-ubuntu-v0.5a/avm2-libc/include/machine/_types.h:95:5: warning: "OSX" is not defined
```

Comment: Do you have an actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: The standard trick for getting all defined preprocessor directives should work here too. It's even in the "related" links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With Mac OS X 10.6.7, Xcode 3.2.6 and gcc 4.2.1 I get the following:

```
$ gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null
#define __DBL_MIN_EXP__ (-1021)
#define __FLT_MIN__ 1.17549435e-38F
#define __DEC64_DEN__ 0.000000000000001E-383DD
#define __CHAR_BIT__ 8
#define __WCHAR_MAX__ 2147483647
#define __DBL_DENORM_MIN__ 4.9406564584124654e-324
#define __FLT_EVAL_METHOD__ 0
#define __DBL_MIN_10_EXP__ (-307)
#define __FINITE_MATH_ONLY__ 0
#define __DEC64_MAX_EXP__ 384
#define __SHRT_MAX__ 32767
#define __LDBL_MAX__ 1.18973149535723176502e+4932L
#define __APPLE_CC__ 5666
#define __UINTMAX_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define __DEC32_EPSILON__ 1E-6DF
#define __block __attribute__((__blocks__(byref)))
#define __SCHAR_MAX__ 127
#define __USER_LABEL_PREFIX__ _
#define __STDC_HOSTED__ 1
#define __DEC64_MIN_EXP__ (-383)
#define __DBL_DIG__ 15
#define __FLT_EPSILON__ 1.19209290e-7F
#define __LDBL_MIN__ 3.36210314311209350626e-4932L
#define __DEC32_MAX__ 9.999999E96DF
#define __strong 
#define __APPLE__ 1
#define __DECIMAL_DIG__ 21
#define __LDBL_HAS_QUIET_NAN__ 1
#define __DYNAMIC__ 1
#define __GNUC__ 4
#define __MMX__ 1
#define __FLT_HAS_DENORM__ 1
#define __DBL_MAX__ 1.7976931348623157e+308
#define __DBL_HAS_INFINITY__ 1
#define __DEC32_MIN_EXP__ (-95)
#define OBJC_NEW_PROPERTIES 1
#define __LDBL_HAS_DENORM__ 1
#define __DEC32_MIN__ 1E-95DF
#define __weak __attribute__((objc_gc(weak)))
#define __DBL_MAX_EXP__ 1024
#define __DEC128_EPSILON__ 1E-33DL
#define __SSE2_MATH__ 1
#define __amd64 1
#define __tune_core2__ 1
#define __LONG_LONG_MAX__ 9223372036854775807LL
#define __GXX_ABI_VERSION 1002
#define __FLT_MIN_EXP__ (-125)
#define __x86_64 1
#define __DBL_MIN__ 2.2250738585072014e-308
#define __LP64__ 1
#define __DBL_HAS_QUIET_NAN__ 1
#define __DEC128_MIN__ 1E-6143DL
#define __REGISTER_PREFIX__ 
#define __DBL_HAS_DENORM__ 1
#define __NO_INLINE__ 1
#define __DEC_EVAL_METHOD__ 2
#define __DEC128_MAX__ 9.999999999999999999999999999999999E6144DL
#define __FLT_MANT_DIG__ 24
#define __VERSION__ "4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)"
#define __DEC64_EPSILON__ 1E-15DD
#define __DEC128_MIN_EXP__ (-6143)
#define __ENVIRONMENT_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED__ 1067
#define __SIZE_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define __DEC32_DEN__ 0.000001E-95DF
#define __FLT_RADIX__ 2
#define __LDBL_EPSILON__ 1.08420217248550443401e-19L
#define __SSE_MATH__ 1
#define __k8 1
#define __LDBL_DIG__ 18
#define __x86_64__ 1
#define __FLT_HAS_QUIET_NAN__ 1
#define __FLT_MAX_10_EXP__ 38
#define __LONG_MAX__ 9223372036854775807L
#define __FLT_HAS_INFINITY__ 1
#define __DEC64_MAX__ 9.999999999999999E384DD
#define __DEC64_MANT_DIG__ 16
#define __DEC32_MAX_EXP__ 96
#define __DEC128_DEN__ 0.000000000000000000000000000000001E-6143DL
#define __LITTLE_ENDIAN__ 1
#define __LDBL_MANT_DIG__ 64
#define __CONSTANT_CFSTRINGS__ 1
#define __DEC32_MANT_DIG__ 7
#define __k8__ 1
#define __WCHAR_TYPE__ int
#define __pic__ 2
#define __FLT_DIG__ 6
#define __INT_MAX__ 2147483647
#define __FLT_MAX_EXP__ 128
#define __BLOCKS__ 1
#define __DBL_MANT_DIG__ 53
#define __DEC64_MIN__ 1E-383DD
#define __WINT_TYPE__ int
#define __SSE__ 1
#define __LDBL_MIN_EXP__ (-16381)
#define __MACH__ 1
#define __amd64__ 1
#define __LDBL_MAX_EXP__ 16384
#define __SSP__ 1
#define __LDBL_MAX_10_EXP__ 4932
#define __DBL_EPSILON__ 2.2204460492503131e-16
#define _LP64 1
#define __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__ 1
#define __LDBL_HAS_INFINITY__ 1
#define __INTMAX_MAX__ 9223372036854775807L
#define __FLT_DENORM_MIN__ 1.40129846e-45F
#define __PIC__ 2
#define __FLT_MAX__ 3.40282347e+38F
#define __SSE2__ 1
#define __FLT_MIN_10_EXP__ (-37)
#define __INTMAX_TYPE__ long int
#define __DEC128_MAX_EXP__ 6144
#define __GNUC_MINOR__ 2
#define __DBL_MAX_10_EXP__ 308
#define __LDBL_DENORM_MIN__ 3.64519953188247460253e-4951L
#define __STDC__ 1
#define __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ long int
#define __DEC128_MANT_DIG__ 34
#define __LDBL_MIN_10_EXP__ (-4931)
#define __GNUC_GNU_INLINE__ 1
#define __SSE3__ 1
$
```

Comment: I know this is old but the way I’m used to doing it is e.g. *`touch foo.h ; cpp -dM foo.h`* so invoking the C pre-processor directly and so no need for the *`-E`* option either. Accomplishes the same thing but differently - and maybe for some easier to remember and certainly less complicated to type.

Comment: @Pryftan: well it depends on whether you’re a “neat freak” or someone who doesn’t mind littering their working directory with unnecessary files. ;-)

Comment: I can think of more reasons: more than one way to skin a *`cat`*; it shows a useful feature of the shell (and one I have used often including compiling source code that was on stdout); and there are other reasons too including what you say but not necessarily to do with 'file clutter' (which could be simply removed of course in the command line). Of course the way I did it is probably simpler to type and remember for most people but in the end I was just providing another way. I think I first saw it in the GCC focus but that was years ago.