# Convert code from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: compiler-errors, swift

I've got this line of code in Objective-C and I absolutely need to "translate it" to Swift.

```
BOOL hasBlur = blurRadius > __FLT_EPSILON__
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

> Use of unresolved identifier __FLT_EPSILON_

Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__FLT_EPSILON__` is a predefined macro of the compiler, apparently not available
in Swift. But `<float.h>` defines

```
#define FLT_EPSILON __FLT_EPSILON__
```

and this is available in Swift as well:

```
let hasBlur = blurRadius > FLT_EPSILON
```

**Update:** Starting with Swift 4, `FLT_EPSILON` is deprecated. See [Hiren Panchal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43188160/1187415) for an up-to-date solution.

Answer (score 6):

> For swift 3.1 OR above

```
CGFloat.ulpOfOne
```

OR

```
Double.ulpOfOne
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it comes from a line of Objective C that looked like:

```
#define __FLT_EPSILON__ 1.19209290e-7F
```

(Source: [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333543/what-is-defined-in-mac-os-gcc-for-c)). So you can safely replace it here with its literal value.

Answer (score 0):

just use this: let **FLT_EPSILON** = CGFloat(FLT_EPSILON)