# Floating point limits (double) defined with long double suffix L

Tags: gcc, floating-point

**1.
Question:**

I have a question about the `DBL_MAX` and `DBL_MIN` definition in Linux with gcc v4.8.5.
They are defined in `limit.h` as:

```
#define DBL_MAX     __DBL_MAX__
#define DBL_MIN     __DBL_MIN__
```

where `__DBL_MIN__` and `__DBL_MAX__` are compiler specific and can be obtained by:

```
$ gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null
...
#define __DBL_MAX__ ((double)1.79769313486231570815e+308L)
#define __DBL_MIN__ ((double)2.22507385850720138309e-308L)
...
```

My question is:
Why are the values defined as `long double` with suffix `L` and then casted back to a `double`?

**2.
Question:**

Why is the `__DBL_MIN_10_EXP__` defined with `-307` but the minimum exponent is `-308` as it is used above in the `DBL_MIN` macro? In the case of the maximum exponent it is defined with `308` which I can understand as it is used by the `DBL_MAX` macro.

```
#define __DBL_MAX_10_EXP__ 308
#define __DBL_MIN_10_EXP__ (-307)
```

---

**Not part of the question, just observations I made:**

By the way using Windows with Visual Studio 2015 there are just the `DBL_MAX` and `DBL_MIN` macros defined without the compiler specific redirection to the versions with the underscore. Further the minimum positive double value `DBL_MIN` and the maximum double value `DBL_MAX` are a little bit greater than the values from my Linux gcc compiler (just compared to the defined macros from gcc v4.8.5 above):

```
#define DBL_MAX        1.7976931348623158e+308
#define DBL_MIN        2.2250738585072014e–308
```

Moreover the Microsoft compiler set the `long double` limits to the values of a `double`, seems that it doesn't support a real `long double` implementation.

Comment: Just a guess: As base10 floats do not exactly match base2 floats, getting the *exact* amount might require the cast.

Comment: See also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333543/what-is-defined-in-mac-os-gcc-for-c

Comment: VS, the compiler, (not Windows, the OS) supports `long double` as a distinct type than `double`.  It just has the same encoding as `double`.  So using `long double` affords scant benefit there

Comment: " Further that minimum positive double value is greater and the maximum double value is smaller than the values fro mmy Linux gcc compiler:" How did you determine this?  Is that by comparing the `double`  "1.7976931348623158e+308` converts to versus `((double)1.79769313486231570815e+308L)`?  or are you comparing source codes?

Comment: @chux: Just comparing the defined values nothing more.

Comment: MSVC is not standard compliant since over 18 years. Wondering why it does not behave standard compliant thus is pointless.

Comment: @Olaf: Yes that's true, I always fall over such things because I'm developing for both Windows and Linux. The `snprintf()` function is a nice example where both platforms behave different and Microsoft doesn't give a damn about what the standard says...

Comment: @AndreKampling: AFAIK gcc and clang can be used on both platforms. Leaves the problems with libc, though.

Comment: Unrelated: thanks for the quick edit on my answer ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifying binary floating point numbers in decimal has subtle issues.

> Why are the values defined as long double with suffix L and then casted back to a double?

With typical [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), the maximum finite value is about `1.795e+308` or exactly.

```
179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368
```

The numbers of digits needed to convert to a unique `double` may be as many as `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG`  (typically 17 and at least 10).  In any case, using exponential notation is certainly clear without being overly precise.

```
/*
1 2345678901234567 */          // Sorted 
1.79769313486231550856124...   // DBL_MAX next smallest for reference
1.79769313486231570814527...   // Exact
1.79769313486231570815e+308L   // gcc
1.7976931348623158e+308        // VS (just a hair closer to exact than "next largerst")
1.7976931348623159077293....   // DBL_MAX next largest if not limited by range
```

Various compilers may not convert this string exactly as hoped.  Sometimes ignoring some least significant digits - although this is controlled by the compiler.

Another source of subtle conversion differences, and **I expect this is why the 'L' is added**, the `double` computation is affected by the processor's floating point unit which might not have *exact* adherence to IEEE standards.  The worse result could be that the `1.797...e+308` constant converts to *infinity* due to minute conversion errors the "code to a `double`" *using double math*.  By converting to a `long double`, those `long double` conversion errors are very small.  Then converting the `long double` result to `double` rounds to the hoped for number.

In short, forcing `L` math insures the constant is not inadvertently made an *infinity*.

I would expect the following which matches neither *gcc* nor *VS* to be sufficient with a compliant IEEE 754 standard [FPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_unit).

```
#define __DBL_MAX__ 1.7976931348623157e+308
```

The cast back to `double` is to make `DBL_MAX` a `double`.  This would meet many code's expectations that a `DBL_MAX` is a `double` and not a `long double`.   I see no specification that requires this though.

> Why is the **DBL_MIN_10_EXP** defined with -307 but the minimum exponent is -308?

That is to comply with the definition of `DBL_MIN_10_EXP`.  "... minimum negative integer such that 10 raised to that power is in the range of normalized floating-point numbers"   The non-integer answer is between -307 and -308, so the minimum integer in range is -307.

> observation part

Although VS treats `long double` as a distinct type, the same encoding as `double` is used, thus there is no numeric advantage in using `L`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Nice explanation!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the L suffix is used.

[This](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html) site has an overview of IEEE 754 floating point.

The exponent is 11 bits, with an offset of 1023. However exponents of 0 and 2047 are reserved for special numbers. So this means that the exponent can vary from 2046-1023=1023 to 1-1023=-1022.

So for the max normalized value we have an exponent of 2^1023. The max value for the mantissa is just below 2 (1.111 etc with 52 1s after the point, in binary) which is ~2*2^1023 = ~1.79e308.

For the min normalized value we have an exponent of 2^-1022. The min mantissa is exactly 1  giving us a value of 1*2^-1022 = ~2.22e-308. So far so good.

DBL_MIN_10_EXP and DBL_MAX_10_EXP are the min/max exponents of 10 that are normalized. For the max 1e308 is less than ~1.79e308 so the value is 308. For the min, 1e-308 is too small - it is lower than ~2.22e-308. 1e-307 is greater than ~2.22e-308 so the value is -307.

Comment: Thank you very nice explanation!