# how to find the source of some macros

Tags: c++, c, macros

There are many places for defining a macro.When the macro is defined in our own project by us,the are easy to find the definition position for them.
But when i try to learn some famous open source project,i am frequently pestered by the question:where to find the source of the macros,if i can not get it's definition,i won't understand some of them (e.g. some of them can be guessed by their name).
for example,some statement from apache:

```
#if defined(__osf__) && defined(__alpha),

#elif defined(__NSIG)
```

as for my knowledge,i know there are some possible originating place for a macro:

1. from this project itself,in some source file(this is the easiest,because we can find it by some tool)
2. from some header file of some 3rd  lib ,we can grep it
3. from c/c++ standard header file(where are they in linux?)
4. from the os (where are they in linux?)
5. automatically generated by the configure tool(it is bitter,i have no idea)
6. from the compiler tool like gcc/g++,or in the makefile we can define some macro

I have some question to consult:

1. how to differentiate them between os defined and gcc/g++ defined and configure tool generated macros？ do they have some characteristic respectively?
2. how to find the source of  those defined by os or by standard C or compiler? e.g.,using `grep` or `find` utilities
3. what does it mean if one macro such as `__strange___` can not be find by combing the whole machine (`cd /;grep __strange___ -r`)?

Thanks for telling the principle and the method to distinguish them and ,to find the source of them!

Comment: Any decent IDE should help you in searching *any* symbol name not just a macro name.Source Insight is one such code analysis tool.

Comment: @Als: *any* is a bit strong. Symbols constructed in a makefile and passed as command line arguments can be very hard to find. Symbols generated inside some program that invokes the compiler via `exec` can be impossible to find other than via RTFM.

Comment: @DavidHammen; We are obviously talking of symbol names which an IDE or tool *can see*.I think that it is a given.

Comment: Source Insight is one such code analysis tool--------hi,Als,Source Insight can only find those macros inside the project,it can not find macros defined by os and c standard header and others.If i am wrong on this point,May you tell me how to use it?tks

Answer (score 59):

A simple, quick way to find out where a macro has been defined is to redefine the macro and check compiler's Warning/Error message.

```
#include <windows.h>
#define min(a,b) nonsense

mintest.cpp(3) : warning C4005: 'min' : macro redefinition
    C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\windef.h(194) : see previous definition of 'min'
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working by default with gcc. Is it necessary to turn up a verbosity setting? gcc just complains about the redefinition, but doesn't give a hint

Answer (score 15):

> 1. how to differentiate them between os defined and gcc/g++ defined and configure tool generated macros？ do they have some characteristic respectively?

The vast majority are defined in some header file somewhere. `gcc -dN -E` can be of help here. Caveat: If you use this approach, you need to invoke `gcc -dN -E` with the same include paths, the same `-D<name>` command line options, the same environment variables such as `CPATH`, ..., as you do when you compile your source to object files.

> 1. how to find the source of those defined by os or by standard C or compiler? e.g.,using grep or find utilities

RTFM. Read the fine manual.

> 1. what does it mean if one macro such as `__strange__` can not be find by combing the whole machine `(cd /;grep __strange___ -r)`?

It could just mean that that symbol isn't defined on your computer. Suppose the code in question is from some open source package that targets a boatload of different systems, different compilers, some of which are not quite compliant with the C++ standard. The typical approach is to use `#ifdef __some_bizarre_os__` in key parts of the code. That symbol will only be defined on machines running the Bizarre OS -- not on yours.

Unfortunately, that's not the only case. The symbol might well be defined even if your grep can't find it anywhere. The makefile could concatenate two strings, `-D__str` and `ange__` to form a single command line argument to the compiler. The option `-D__strange__` might be hiding in plain sight in one of your environment variables used by the makefile. The ~/.tcshrc files that some projects mandate can be incredibly convoluted.

**Update**
`gcc -dM -E` shows the definitions of the macros, but not where they were defined. A much better options is to use `gcc -dN -E` and then filter out lines that don't start with an initial `#`.

Comment: RTFM. Read the fine manual.
__beg your pardon,you mean the manpage for "find",would you show me a simple demo for find some strange macro?

Comment: does each type of macro has some feature in their apperance? e.g.,is there some rule as:macros defined by os start with "_",and some other kind starts from one underscore ""，and so on ?

Comment: @user624866 - The manuals or man pages you need to read is that for the compiler. Example: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html . With regard to macros with leading double underscores or a leading underscore followed by a capital letter: Those are reserved names, reserved for use by the vendor (the authors of the compiler, the team that made your Linux distro). Note well: Not everyone follows this rule.

Comment: David Hammen ————what the abbrevation "RTFM" stand for?(beg pardon,i am chinese,not native english speaker)

Comment: The makefile could concatenate two strings___several buddies metiond this, may some body make an example here?

Comment: I like the update: `gcc -dN -E` identifies your "<command line>" defines explicitly.  Cool.

Comment: I find `-E -dD` or `-E -dU` more useful than `-E -dN`. The gcc manual says that `-dD` is `-dM` minus predefined macros plus the result of preprocessing, `-dN` is `-dD` with only the names, i.e. minus the macro expansions, and `-dU` is `-dD` with only expanded/tested macros (producing more compact output).

Comment: Good to know about `-dN`—I used to know `-dM` only. It seems new, and clang 10 does not support `-dN`, but `-dM` only. Also bad that neither `-dM` nor `-dN` can be found in the output of `gcc -v --help 2>&1`, at least not in GCC 7 and 8.

Answer (score 6):

gcc compiler defined macros can be revealed by

```
gcc  -dM -E a.c
```

Other than that, they all come from included files and sources.

If you can't find the macro, that means the conditional will be evaluated to false.

You can also use the -v option, it reveal where it finds its default include directories.

To find out which file the macro is from:

```
gcc -E $your_compile_options $your_c_file | \
egrep "^# " | grep -v '<'| cut -f 2 -d '"' | \
sort | uniq |
while read line
    do
            grep -l $your_macro $line
    done
```

Comment: They can also be defined on the command line for gcc. `gcc -DFOO=BAR ...` will define the FOO macro.

Comment: if you put them on command line, you already know what they are.

Comment: Not if they're getting put there by your applications build system.

Comment: @pizza: Very often, the command line is constructed by concatenating the compiler and linker flags of libraries you use; for instance, by concatenating the `CXXFLAGS` as given by Python, Perl or whatever other libraries you may be using.

Comment: Re *they all come from included files and sources* - Not always. A tool that invokes the compiler might define symbols when it calls `exec`. `#ifdef SWIG` is a good example.

Comment: They would have shown up already in gcc -dM -E, those that don't they came from source files (or modified source files from tools output), but still from source files.

Comment: @pizza: No, they wouldn't. I previously gave you a specific (but easy) example. Sometimes those names come from headers that aren't in the default search path (so `gcc -dM -E` will miss them), sometimes they come from the command line (so `gcc -dM -E` will miss them, and all the other names whose definition is triggered by those names defined as command line arguments). Sometimes you won't find where that `-DFOO_BAR_BAZ` came from because the tool is concatenating strings. There is no `FOO_BAR_BAZ` in any file, anywhere.

Comment: touch foo.h; gcc -dM -E -DFOO=BAR foo.h | grep OO

Comment: gcc -dM -E signals.c >gccdm,cat gccdm,only shows a large number of define directive,as:#define APR_ENOLOCK (APR_OS_START_ERROR + 9)
#define apr_get_netos_error() (errno)
#defineSI_TIMER                                                       but no information as for in which header file they are defined

Comment: how to find which file they are from? can we only use grep?tks

Comment: gcc -dM -E $(your_compile_options) empty_file.c > not_from_source_file then you do the same with your file, the delta is added by all the files you included.

Comment: @user624866: You don't want `gcc -dM -E` if the goal is to find where the symbols are defined.

Comment: David Hammen .You don't want gcc -dM -E if the goal is to find where the symbols are defined  _____both you and pizza tell me the method.but i don't know what yo mean ,you mean gcc -dN -E ? if no so,please show me your method,tks.i need to know those symbols defined by gcc/g++ and os header file.

Comment: You can also read the diagnotics form gcc -dD -E , it shows you where the macros are from if they came from included files.

Answer (score 4):

As others said, `gcc` with one of `-d` options should be used to **find out where the macro is defined**. Those options are not outputted by `gcc -v --help`, so they must be read using [the manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/), chapter [3.11](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options), search for `-dCHARS`.

Finally my steps are:

1. Use `gcc ... -E -dD`
2. Find the definition in the output file
3. Search backwards for `#` (a hash and a space) to reveal the file

Answer (score 2):

If you're studying some open source project I assume that you have set it up so that you can build it. Choose one file that contains the macro you're looking for and use your compiler to generate a preprocessed file. The actual option depends on the compiler you're using, it's -E for gcc, you can find some more information [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html).

Note that you'll probably have to use your project's build system to actually compile your file and see which options you need for the preprocessor run to succeed.

Once you have your preprocessed file, just search for your macro. There are preprocessor options that generate the pathname for each included file.

UPDATE:
This approach obviously doesn't work, because your macro is expanded by the processor. So, unless you can recognize its expanded form or its effects, it would be of little use.

What could be somewhat more useful is to get the compiler to print out the exact sequence of included files. This is achieved in gcc with the -H option.

Comment: tks for enlighting me,Nicola Musatti.I think preprocessor will expand all macro so that get prepared to compile.But it will indicate whence each macro come from?(e.g,can it tell me this is an os defined macro,a standard c header defined ,which file it is from?)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like these macros are compilation constants.

It is good practice to use such macros to tell compiler that this part of code need to be compiled and this part of code is not to be compiled.

If you are not able to search them in your project workspace then you should go through the program flow and decide which part of code is required by your appication and define the respective macro.

For example;

```
#ifdef (_CASE1_)

...
...
...

#elif (_CASE2_)

...
...
...

#endif
```

now in above example, if the code covered under `_CASE1_` is required by your application then you must define `_CASE1_`. e.g. `#define _CASE1_`

hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

You should use a IDE like Eclipse where you can simply right click on the macro and click Open Declaration and it will send you to the file and line the macro is defined.

Sometimes some macros aren't even defined in the header files as they are given as flags to the gnu compiler (example: -DMYMACRO).

Answer (score 0):

I usually find Vim enough for this: `CTRL-W CTRL-I` and `[I` are my favourite. (These are all kinds of identifiers, and `CTRL-W CTRL-D` and `[D` are for macros only.) You can type `:help include-search` for the whole list of the available commands.

For these to work, you should have your `path` option in Vim set up correctly. Type `:set path?` to see your current setting. Run `gcc -v -E -x c++ - </dev/null`, look for `#include <...> search starts here:`, and copy the directories and add them to your `path` (in your `.vimrc`). (What I do is to extract the directories and store them into an environment variable in `.bash_profile`, and refer to that in my `.vimrc`, as in `set path=$INCLUDE_PATH`.) You may need to add any project-specific include directories to your `path` as well.