# Find place where some macro was #define-ed

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012

The bottom line: building with VS2012, there's a macro (WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN) defined in my project I can't find #define-ed anywhere: not in C/C++ --> Preprocessor, not inherited from parent or project dependencies (microsoft.cpp.props), not in the command-line. It is not mentioned anywhere in the vcxproj.

Compiling a single source/header in the project, I find it is defined already on the first line of the header. Putting this at the top of my header:

```
#pragma once

#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#pragma  message ("WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN not defined")
#else
#pragma  message ("WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN defined")
#endif
/* ... */
```

Printed "`WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN defined`" to the build output console.

According to suggestions that were posted [in another - very similar - question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257455/how-to-find-the-source-of-some-macros), I tried to re-define the macro:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN 123

#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#pragma  message ("WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN not defined")
#else
#pragma  message ("WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN defined")
#endif
```

and obviously get a build warning:

> C:\sys\inc\myproj\myproj_someheader.h(5): warning C4005: 'WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN' : macro redefinition
>
> command-line arguments :  see previous definition of 'WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN'

However, as previously mentioned, not in that project configuration (`vcxproj`), and also not in any common properties, is that macro currently defined.

**My question is**: How can I find where that macro actually came from?

Comment: It's defined in your implementation, not in your code. Look it up: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg/using-the-windows-headers

Comment: @JesperJuhl - doesn't seem right. It was defined before a single header was included, and when re-defined - the warning points to the command-line. Besides, as described in the long part - when built on another machine (Win 10) it wasn't definded at all.

Comment: Use a tool like grep.

Comment: There's also VC_EXTRALEAN.

Comment: @JesperJuhl - I don't need another definition, just a way to understand where the definition I have came from.

Comment: @uv_ I misspoke; it's not *defined* by your implementation, but *used* by it *if you define it*.

Comment: @NeilButterworth - on what?

Comment: "I actually need that macro defined in all of my projects" ... I dont really understand what is the problem then with the macro being defined somewhere

Comment: On your source code tree and your system headers.

Comment: @NeilButterworth - already mentioned the macro was found defined on the first line of the first header, before any other code or system headers were #included.

Comment: according to the message it looks like the macro is defined in the command line arguments. Check your compilation command.

Comment: Use a file manager like Far https://farmanager.com/index.php?l=en that can search in files. Search for any files under the project i.e. name=`*` with that macro. You'll prolly find out the issue is caused by some incremental build artifact. When you encounter weird stuff like this, be sure to close project & clean all temp files, debug/release/.vc/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the project properties (Project Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions and at C/C++->Command Line), the vcxproj itself (looked if there are Preprocessor Definitions configured for the specific source file), common properties (configured in Microsoft.Cpp.Props), headers and source-code, nowhere where WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN was defined, it turns out it was defined by the **%CL%** environment variable.

Comment: So how did %CL% get defined?  It is *NOT* a default from a standard MSVS install, nor is it defined in an MSVS "Developer command prompt".  Where did it come from on your system?

Comment: I guess it was added as part of our development environment. The point is - that's another place to look which isn't reported in the project properties. I only found the mismatch when I set (Options --> Projects and Solutions --> Build and Run -->) "MSBuild project build output verbosity" to "Diagnostic"

Comment: Cool - thank you.  For following up, for the clarification ... and for the *GREAT* tip about `Options > Projects/Solutions > Build/Run > "MSBuild project build output verbosity" => "Diagnostic" `.  When you get a chance, please "accept" your resolution.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` anywhere on your development system.

There are plenty of `#ifdef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` (or equivalent).

The point is that *you* define it, if you need it/want it.

> http://web.archive.org/web/20121219084749/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/166474
>
> VC_EXTRALEAN and WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN are used to exclude rarely-used
>   services from Windows headers. VC_EXTRALEAN can only be used in MFC
>   projects, but WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN can be used in any project.

If you want to see how macros are being expanded for your particular project, you can use the `/P` switch, and look at the corresponding .i file(s):

> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/162e8850-f442-4283-a419-6c328684388e/showing-how-a-macro-is-expanded?forum=vclanguage
>
> The C++ compiler has a /P switch which means pre-process to a file.
>
> You can enable this from Project -> Properties -> Configuration
>   Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocess to a File.
>
> After this option is set, you will get a .i file for every .cpp file.
>
> Be warned that these .i files are huge files.

---

ADDENDUM:

1. I went into MSVS 2015 and created a quick'n'dirty test program:

   ```
   // TestWin32LeanAndMean.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
   //    
   #include "stdafx.h"
   #include <iostream>

   #ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
   #pragma  message ("WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN not defined")
   #else
   #pragma  message ("WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN defined")
   #endif

   int main()
   {
       std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   Compiler log:

   1>------ Build started: Project: TestWin32LeanAndMean, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
   1>  stdafx.cpp
   1>  TestWin32LeanAndMean.cpp
   1>  WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN not defined
   1>  TestWin32LeanAndMean.vcxproj -> D:\paul\proj\msvs_2015\TestWin32LeanAndMean\Debug\TestWin32LeanAndMean.exe
   ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
2. I then went into Project > Properties > Preprocessor, and added "WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN":

   MSVS Preprocessor Definitions:

   `_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions);WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`

   The build *still* said "undefined" (?!?)

   1>------ Build started: Project: TestWin32LeanAndMean, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
      1>  stdafx.cpp
      1>  TestWin32LeanAndMean.cpp
      1>  WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN not defined
      1>  TestWin32LeanAndMean.vcxproj -> D:\paul\proj\msvs_2015\TestWin32LeanAndMean\Debug\TestWin32LeanAndMean.exe
3. So I manually edited my .vcsproj file and rebuilt:

   TestWin32LeanAndMean.vcxproj:

   ```
   <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
     <ClCompile>
       <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN;WIN32;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
       ...
   <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
     <ClCompile>
       <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
       ...
   <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
     <ClCompile>
       <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN;WIN32;NDEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
       ...
   <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
     <ClCompile>
       <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN;NDEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
     ...
   ```

   **I finally got WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN" defined:**

   ```
   1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: TestWin32LeanAndMean, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
   1>  stdafx.cpp
   1>  TestWin32LeanAndMean.cpp
   1>  WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN defined
   1>  TestWin32LeanAndMean.vcxproj -> D:\paul\proj\msvs_2015      \TestWin32LeanAndMean\Debug\TestWin32LeanAndMean.exe
   ```
4. To see exactly what the MSVS macro preprocessor is doing, you should be able to use "/P" ("Preprocess to a file").
5. In my experience - and in the test above - "WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN" is typically *NOT DEFINED* in the environment.
6. If it *IS* somehow defined, the places to look would be:

   a) MSVS > Project > Properties

   b) Windows Explorer > Project > .vcxproj file

   c) MSVS Install folder > Templates > ProjectTemplates

Comment: Excuse me, but that's not an answer to my question. I specifically mentioned that testing for if WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN was defined returned it was indeed, and my question was how to find the definition. I know what is it for, I know I need to define it myself if I need to, and don't need another macro like it.

Comment: @uv_ It _is_ an answer. If you know you need to define it yourself, and you did not do that, then where do you think you will find it?! It does not exist yet.