# Get build errors after linking gdi plus

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2019, gdi+

I get stuff like this : 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusBitmap.h(87,5): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation

Here are the screenshots to the problem :
https://ibb.co/x7j2cDw

https://ibb.co/Cv77ZVs

Code at the top: 
https://ibb.co/Vm1v2gh

Code at the top:

```
#include "framework.h"
#include "Someapp.h"
#include "../SkinClass/skin.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
```

errors :

```
1>Someapp.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusImaging.h(84,54): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusImaging.h(84,15): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char [37]' to 'int'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusImaging.h(84,15): message : There is no context in which this conversion is possible
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusImaging.h(85,1): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'IImageBytes'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusImaging.h(85,15): error C2059: syntax error: 'public'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusImaging.h(86,1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusImaging.h(86,1): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusImaging.h(291,15): error C3646: 'id': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusImaging.h(291,15): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusHeaders.h(396,6): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'IStream'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusHeaders.h(407,19): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'IStream'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusHeaders.h(417,27): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'IStream'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusHeaders.h(455,40): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'PROPID'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusHeaders.h(456,40): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'PROPID'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusHeaders.h(457,38): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'PROPID'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusHeaders.h(465,41): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'PROPID'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusHeaders.h(483,13): error C2535: 'Gdiplus::Image::Image(void)': member function already defined or declared
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusHeaders.h(396): message : see declaration of 'Gdiplus::Image::Image'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusHeaders.h(518,6): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'IStream'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusHeaders.h(529,20): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'IStream'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusHeaders.h(773,33): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'IStream'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusHeaders.h(828,10): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'IStream'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusHeaders.h(828,10): error C2535: 'Gdiplus::Metafile::Metafile(void)': member function already defined or declared
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusHeaders.h(773): message : see declaration of 'Gdiplus::Metafile::Metafile'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusHeaders.h(835,10): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'IStream'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusHeaders.h(835,10): error C2535: 'Gdiplus::Metafile::Metafile(void)': member function already defined or declared
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusHeaders.h(773): message : see declaration of 'Gdiplus::Metafile::Metafile'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusHeaders.h(844,10): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'IStream'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusHeaders.h(844,10): error C2535: 'Gdiplus::Metafile::Metafile(void)': member function already defined or declared
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusHeaders.h(773): message : see declaration of 'Gdiplus::Metafile::Metafile'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusHeaders.h(870,20): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'IStream'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusHeaders.h(938,5): error C2535: 'Gdiplus::Metafile::Metafile(void)': member function already defined or declared
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusHeaders.h(773): message : see declaration of 'Gdiplus::Metafile::Metafile'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(1145,25): error C2065: 'IStream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(1145,34): error C2065: 'stream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(1145,52): error C2065: 'image': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(1145,42): error C2275: 'Gdiplus::GpImage': illegal use of this type as an expression
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusGpStubs.h(66): message : see declaration of 'Gdiplus::GpImage'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(1145,57): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(1151,28): error C2065: 'IStream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(1151,37): error C2065: 'stream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(1151,55): error C2065: 'image': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(1151,45): error C2275: 'Gdiplus::GpImage': illegal use of this type as an expression
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusGpStubs.h(66): message : see declaration of 'Gdiplus::GpImage'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(1151,60): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(1168,46): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'IStream'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(1256,65): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'PROPID'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(1259,48): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'PROPID'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(1262,44): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'PROPID'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(1274,47): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'PROPID'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(1298,28): error C2065: 'IStream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(1298,37): error C2065: 'stream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(1298,56): error C2065: 'bitmap': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(1298,45): error C2275: 'Gdiplus::GpBitmap': illegal use of this type as an expression
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusGpStubs.h(67): message : see declaration of 'Gdiplus::GpBitmap'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(1298,62): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(1304,31): error C2065: 'IStream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(1304,40): error C2065: 'stream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(1304,59): error C2065: 'bitmap': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(1304,48): error C2275: 'Gdiplus::GpBitmap': illegal use of this type as an expression
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusGpStubs.h(67): message : see declaration of 'Gdiplus::GpBitmap'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(1304,65): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(2235,5): error C2065: 'IStream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(2235,25): error C2065: 'stream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(2236,25): error C2065: 'header': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(2236,5): error C2275: 'Gdiplus::MetafileHeader': illegal use of this type as an expression
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetaHeader.h(116): message : see declaration of 'Gdiplus::MetafileHeader'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(2237,5): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(2255,32): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'IStream'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(2275,30): error C2065: 'IStream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(2275,40): error C2065: 'stream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(2275,61): error C2065: 'metafile': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(2275,48): error C2275: 'Gdiplus::GpMetafile': illegal use of this type as an expression
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusGpStubs.h(68): message : see declaration of 'Gdiplus::GpMetafile'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(2275,69): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(2322,5): error C2065: 'IStream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(2322,25): error C2065: 'stream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(2323,5): error C2275: 'HDC': illegal use of this type as an expression
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\shared\windef.h(80): message : see declaration of 'HDC'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(2323,25): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'referenceHdc'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(2333,5): error C2065: 'IStream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(2333,25): error C2065: 'stream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(2334,5): error C2275: 'HDC': illegal use of this type as an expression
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\shared\windef.h(80): message : see declaration of 'HDC'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusFlat.h(2334,25): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'referenceHdc'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusPath.h(145,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'byte'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(80,23): error C2065: 'IStream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(80,32): error C2065: 'stream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(80,11): error C7550: 'Gdiplus::Metafile::{ctor}': the qualified name in this context names a constructor, not a type
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(81,1): error C2448: 'Gdiplus::Metafile::{ctor}': function-style initializer appears to be a function definition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(199,8): error C2065: 'IStream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(199,28): error C2065: 'stream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(200,8): error C2275: 'HDC': illegal use of this type as an expression
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\shared\windef.h(80): message : see declaration of 'HDC'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(200,28): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'referenceHdc'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(204,1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(204,1): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(216,8): error C2065: 'IStream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(216,28): error C2065: 'stream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(217,8): error C2275: 'HDC': illegal use of this type as an expression
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\shared\windef.h(80): message : see declaration of 'HDC'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(217,28): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'referenceHdc'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(223,1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(223,1): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(235,8): error C2065: 'IStream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(235,28): error C2065: 'stream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(236,8): error C2275: 'HDC': illegal use of this type as an expression
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\shared\windef.h(80): message : see declaration of 'HDC'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(236,28): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'referenceHdc'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(242,1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(242,1): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(284,8): error C2065: 'IStream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(284,28): error C2065: 'stream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(285,28): error C2065: 'header': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(285,9): error C2275: 'Gdiplus::MetafileHeader': illegal use of this type as an expression
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetaHeader.h(116): message : see declaration of 'Gdiplus::MetafileHeader'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(286,5): error C2761: 'GetMetafileHeader': redeclaration of member is not allowed
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusMetafile.h(287,1): error C2448: 'Gdiplus::Metafile::GetMetafileHeader': function-style initializer appears to be a function definition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusBitmap.h(50,8): error C2065: 'IStream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusBitmap.h(50,17): error C2065: 'stream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusBitmap.h(51,8): error C2275: 'BOOL': illegal use of this type as an expression
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\shared\minwindef.h(157): message : see declaration of 'BOOL'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusBitmap.h(51,13): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'useEmbeddedColorManagement'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusBitmap.h(53,1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusBitmap.h(53,1): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusBitmap.h(85,8): error C2065: 'IStream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusBitmap.h(85,17): error C2065: 'stream': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusBitmap.h(86,8): error C2275: 'BOOL': illegal use of this type as an expression
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\shared\minwindef.h(157): message : see declaration of 'BOOL'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusBitmap.h(87,5): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
1>Done building project "Someapp.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Here is line 84 i was asked to give for C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusImaging.h

GdiplusImaging.h

```
MIDL_INTERFACE("025D1823-6C7D-447B-BBDB-A3CBC3DFA2FC")
```

a screenshot of the problem :

https://ibb.co/F4W8CDp

Comment: Is my question now satisfactory?

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2019.

Comment: Its possible if you show some code around line 84 of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\GdiplusImaging.h` that this could help debug the issue. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: I showed line 84.

Comment: As i was surfing the internet, it seems this problem is something to do with WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN  (well, atleast i think it does). Note : I haven't solved the problem yet.

Comment: ***it seems this problem is something to do with WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN*** I thought about that when I saw the errors. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040133/what-does-defining-win32-lean-and-mean-exclude-exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040133/what-does-defining-win32-lean-and-mean-exclude-exactly)

Comment: Also related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54188263/find-place-where-some-macro-was-define-ed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54188263/find-place-where-some-macro-was-define-ed)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by going to file called "framework.h",which I believe is called in previous versions of visual studio "header.h", and I commented out the line #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN.

Comment: I will admit i did forget to provide in code but it was there in one of the image I provided.Actually I didn't forget it was ``` marks in stackoverflow question submission where it was hidden.

Comment: My advice is next time please avoid screenshots of text.

Comment: "called in previous versions of visual studio `header.h`"  Did you perhaps mean `stdafx.h` which many many versions of the Visual C++ New Project Wizard would create for you?