# How to find a declaration of a variable/function in c code?

Tags: c, declaration

Maybe it is a dummy question but for a long time I have been trying to read a C code written by others and each time unsuccessfully. When reading the code I stumble upon some macros or a function declaration of which I am just unable to find as they come from another libraries where it is not obvious from which one. For example, I stumbled on "STREQ" macros in [cat.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/cat.c) code which a source of "cat" tool and can't find its declaration in the code.

So, the question is:

Is there any way to find declarations of macros, functions within a code manually or using IDE features (which I am not aware of) without googling its name to check if it an STL function or not? How do you do it usually?

Comment: Any good IDE has a "find definition" feature.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257455/how-to-find-the-source-of-some-macros and consider tools like ctags, cscope and codequery

Comment: usually the IDE will help, e.g. with a function like "Go to Definition" in the menu or context menu when having the respective function/makro selected in the text. Which IDE are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can run [c preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) and examine its output for all the macro expansion, header file inclusion, conditional compilation, etc.

The compilation flag is -E in gnu c compiler.

gcc -E cat.c

Comment: This only applies if the definition in question was indeed a macro and not a function