# is there a way to list symbols that are defined in c/c++ by #define

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, compiler-errors, debug-symbols

I am using eclipse and keep getting an undefined reference to `__assert_func' error in my c/c++ code.

I am wondering if there is a way to tell what is being defined ( # define ****). I can manually go through my files, but I am working with a lot of them and this would take a while. Is there a compiler option or a tool that could list these for me?

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is dependent on the compiler. You can read this if you're running GCC.

[GCC dump preprocessor defines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines)

Comment: I am using the Cross GCC/G++ compiler this will help a lot Thank you

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the correct answer in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Undefined reference has nothing to do with `#define`s. It is a linker error, you may have forgotten to link against a .lib/.a file.

Comment: Well, it could (most like is) an `#define assert(x) assert_func(x, __FILE__, __LINE__)` or some such.

Comment: Csq - Thank you I think I may need to include a lib is there a way to find which one I need? google?   I am currently linking with -nostdlib

Comment: I think asserts are in the standard lib, so try with removing the -nostdlib option

Comment: It returns many unresolved inclusion errors without -nostdlib. I have to use -nostdlib in order to implement what I am working on.  I am including the assert.h file which needs certain defines in order to define the function... I appreciate your time/help

Comment: It might not be possible. assert is part of the stdlib. You can write your own assert-like function though. Or ask a new question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can usually produce the pre-processor output from the compiler - e.g. `g++ -E myprog.cpp > myprog.i`. I think `CL -E` does the same thing in Visual Studio, and other compilers tend to have a similar option.

It does sound like your missing function is part of a `ASSERT` or `assert` macro.

Comment: I am including assert.h but I don't think I have the correct defines for the header to define the function

Comment: The problem, most likely, is that you are not linking something that you should be linking - but I don't know, as you haven't shown us any code... Try to break down the problem to a small one - it's most likely going to solve your issue. I find putting `#if 0 / #endif` around the content of functions (or outside of functions) helps reduce the amount of code that is "Under suspicion".

Comment: Thank you for the tip I will defiantly try that. I am working on implementing a timer class for an ARM processor provided by Atmel and I need to either define the correct thing or find out what I should be linking. I'm sure its a simple issue, I am pretty new to this sort of thing. Thank you again for your help!