# Error: Type 'EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY' could not be resolved when tried to use Open GL purely in C++ NativeActivity in NDK

Tags: c++, opengl-es, android-ndk

Can anyone suggest how start learning Open GL implementation in pure C++ in a NativeActivity in Android NDK without using jni.

I have tried running the sample `NativeActivity` that comes with the NDK setup, but I am not able to run it. Giving error

`Type 'EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY' could not be resolved`

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this error.

Comment: The answer is one google search away.

Comment: the results i am getting is to use Open GL from Java and C++ using jni. I want ot use it purely in C++ and not from Java

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html

Comment: I tried running this exmaple on my phone using eclipse but it gives error `Type 'EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY' could not be resolved`

Comment: Could be anything, debug. On one of my tablets, the Java example of `GLSurfaceView` does not work either any if anything should work, that definetly should. I suggest, you change your question to ask about the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the error

just add the statement `typedef void* EGLNativeDisplayType;` before the statement
`#include <EGL/egl.h>` in `main.c` in the `NativeActivity`

Comment: It's not a good idea to define platform-specific types yourself.  This should be coming out of `EGL/eglplatform.h`.  The part I don't understand, looking at your question, is why the compiler would claim that `EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY` is a *type*.

Comment: you are absolutely correct, but when I was checking out the header file `EGL/eglplatform.h`, I found that its definition is dependent on the macros `__ANDROID__` or `ANDROID`. May be the problem lies in this only.

Comment: IIRC, those should be defined for you by the Android NDK compiler configuration.

Comment: true. but I am not able to figure out the option from where I can define it for my NDK compiler configuration.

Comment: Should be baked in -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines for instructions on how to get the list.  When I use that on with the NDK gcc, I see (among 350 other things) `#define __ANDROID__ 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Can be handled by including source SUB directories as well as their parents in 
`project > properties >C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Includes(tab)`.

e.g. add

```
${env_var:ANDROID_NDK}/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include/EGL
```

as well as

```
${env_var:ANDROID_NDK}/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include
```

Maybe the syntax parser (if there is such a thing) misses the sub-folders?

Answer (score 0):

include the 
${env_var:ANDROID_NDK}/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include/EGL
is a partial correct, after this, comment out all content in Application.mk, then close main.c, clean the project, open main.c again, see the error is disappear, then recovery the Application.mk.