# How to use _WIN32 and _CYGWIN_ macros

Tags: c++, c, operating-system

I was trying to detect target operating system using c macros _WIN32 and _ CYGWIN_ but it shows error that _ CYGWIN_ is undeclared.
How to use these macros to find target operating system

Comment: What about `#ifdef _WIN32`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using #ifdef. For example:

```
#ifdef __CYGWIN__
  // Cygwin specific code
#else
  // Other code
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

gcc on cygwin defines the macro `__CYGWIN32__`.

Take a look at [GCC dump preprocessor defines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines) to find all the macros defined by the preprocessor.