# How can I dump all NVCC preprocessor defines?

Tags: cuda, g++, c-preprocessor, nvcc

I want to achieve the same effect as

```
gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null
```

(as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2224334/1593077)) - but for nvcc. That is, I want to dump all of nvcc's preprocessor defines. Alas, nvcc doesn not support `-dM`. What do I do instead?

Comment: You can get a sense of what "extra" preprocessor defines that `nvcc` is specifying when it is using `gcc` under the hood, by specifying the `-v` option while compiling.  Perhaps something like this:  `nvcc -v myfile.cu -o myfile 2>&1 >/dev/null |grep -e "-D"`

Comment: Don't you have to add `-x c`?

Comment: @S.S.Anne: Not for preprocessing you don't. Try it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `-dM`, pass `--compiler-options -dM` to `nvcc`. You should also add `-x cu` since the compiler doesn't know the file type of stdin. So your command line would be

```
nvcc --compiler-options -dM -E -x cu - < /dev/null
```