# How to create a directory without using boost?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, macos, file-io

I want to create a directory in the same path as my program, to ultimately save data to.  To do this I need OS specific calls surrounded by preprocessor branches, but I've never wrote any OS specific code before this point.  I am unsure what headers I need to include, or what functions to use from them.

If the OS are Windows, Mac, and Linux (whatever method would work for most linux distros anyway), what functions and headers should I use?

The reason I don't want to use boost filesystem for this is, I've had difficulty all day compiling it; it's documentation and build system is, uh, too academic/verbose for my simple soul it seems!  Ultimately, I believe maintaining 3 or 4 seperate file loading branches will be faster for me.

Answer (score 3):

On all Unix systems (Linux, Mac OS X, etc.), you should call `mkdir` with two arguments:

```
mkdir(filename, 0755);
```

On Windows, you want to use `_mkdir` with just one argument:

```
_mkdir(filename);
```

So your code should say

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include <direct.h>
rc = _mkdir(filename);
#else
#include <sys/stat.h>
rc = mkdir(filename, 0755);
#endif
```

Comment: `_mkdir` requires the header `<direct.h>` to be included. It's also worth noting that there is a Unicode-aware version `_wmkdir`, that allows to reliably create directories with characters outside the ASCII range.

Answer (score 2):

First, if you want to write cross-platform code (for all of Linux, Windows, MacOSX), you might use some multi-platform framework library like [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) or [Qt](http://qt-project.org/)

Then, if you want [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) specific function to make a directory, use [mkdir](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) function. On Linux, it is  the [mkdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html) syscall (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)...). The documentation explains which headers should be included, and it is part of the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) on Linux.

BTW, on most Linux distributions, you often don't need to *compile* Boost; on Debian-like distributions (e.g. Ubuntu) you can install the `libboost-all-dev` meta-package (all boost related libraries, for development) using `aptitude install libboost-all-dev` or `apt-get install libboost-all-dev`

To get an overview of Linux programming, read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Also, `gcc` (and other C or C++ compilers) predefines a set of preprocessor symbols. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2224357/841108). So in your code, you might simply use `#if linux` ... `#endif` to wrap Linux-specific code.

Notice also that POSIX is a standard specification: you should be able to compile the *same* code on all POSIX compliant operating systems (notably Linux, *BSD, Solaris, MacOSX). Sadly, Windows is not POSIX compliant (even if you can buy a POSIX-compliant kit from MicroSoft)

<sup>Perhaps `mkdir` is available on Windows too....</sup>

Read also [feature_test_macros(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html)

---

Notice also that "create a directory in the same path as my program" is ambiguous. You can run your program in several [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29), each having a different current [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). And quite often (at least on Linux) an executable program is installed in some directory (e.g. `/usr/local/bin/`, `/usr/bin/` or `$HOME/bin/`) mentioned in your `PATH` but unwritable by most programs. Read more about the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard). So I won't [persist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29) your software data in the same directory as your program. Also, you could use [application checkpointing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing) or persist your data using [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) or something else ([PostGreSQL](http://postgresql.org/), [MongoDB](http://mongodb.org/), [JSON](http://json.org/), ...)