# How to predefine header file path in a project

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, header-files, code-composer

I am trying to use the following method to include a project header file:

```
#include FILE_PATH
```

Where `FILE_PATH` is defined as the file to be included.

The project compiles without errors if `FILE_PATH` is include as:

```
#define FILE_PATH "hal/micro/config.h"
#include FILE_PATH
```

But if FILE_PATH is pre-defined as a compiler define option inside the project options, then building the project returns the following error:

> Error #13: Expected a file name

The development software being used is Code Composer Studio version 6.

What am I missing here to pre-define the header file path in a project?

Additional Details:

I am in the process of converting a working project from the IAR embedded workbench IDE to Code Composer Studio. The Pre-define NAME (--define, -D) shown in the picture below are mostly identical to how they were in the IAR project.
[image]

The pre-define name boxed in red is currently the cause of the error, but this could occur with any of the other defines with file pathnames.

[image]

I have tried the suggestion of using the #ifdef statement to at least verify that PLATFORM_HEADER is actually defined and it does seem to be defined. I also checked for typos and there doesn't appear to be any noticeable typos.

[image]

The key reason for wanting to go with the pre-defined macro approach is to avoid individually making changes to numerous files affected by this error.

[image]

I still have not yet tried a command line compile, since I need to reference the manual on how to do so, but I will try as soon as I figure it out.

Comment: Sounds like you are missing a `-DFILE_PATH="hal/micro/config.h" compiler flag.

Comment: Are you sure it is predefined? Check it with `#ifdef`

Comment: Use your command-line for compiling that, and combine with advice from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines Is `FILE_PATH` really defined as it should be? Not perhaps missing the string-markers and unescaped?

Comment: I'm at work and wont be able to test for 2 hours. I'll post back with my results shortly.

Comment: http://ideone.com/U5fj0Z you probably have a typo. In c++11, it's allowed per [cpp.include] 16.2.4

Comment: @Aggieboy - See additional details.

Comment: @stefan - I don't think thats the case here.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - I tried this see additional details for feedback

Comment: @Deduplicator - I am not exactly sure how to do this...I updated the question with additional info. I will be researching how to accomplish this.

Comment: Maybe the IDE does not correctly escape the parameters. Could you try escaping the quotes? You can also try placing `PLATFORM_HEADER` somewhere in the code and see what the compiler would tell you it sees.

Comment: @StenSoft it worked! Write that in an answer so I can give you some credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@StenSoft wrote:

> The IDE does not correctly escape the parameters. You should escape the quotes. You can also try placing PLATFORM_HEADER somewhere in the code and see what the compiler would tell you it sees.

Comment: ([Answered in the comments and converted to a community wiki answer.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))