# How to detect Cross GCC compiler using Macros

Tags: c++, c, gcc, macros

I found this really interesting article: **[C/C++ tip: How to detect the compiler name and version using compiler predefined macros](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/10/c_c_tip_how_detect_compiler_name_and_version_using_compiler_predefined_macros)**

Is it possible to detect by using a Macro if the current compiler is **Cross GCC** (the one used as default with *Eclipse CDT*)?

Comment: I used `#ifdef __arm__` for arm paltform cross compiler

Comment: Why do you even need to know if it is a cross compiler or not?

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to detect, if you are compiling e.g. for ARM, but it is not possible to detect by macro, if you are compiling for ARM on ARM or cros-compiling on x86.

You need support in build system for this and pass your variable to compiler

```
gcc -DIS_CROSSCOMPILING=1
```

Using this [GCC dump preprocessor defines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines) check yourself output of cross compiler and system  compiler. There are lot of defines but nothing about cross compilation.

According to this http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Cross_002dCompilation.html
autotools are performing some check

```
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
```

and I hope that this result can be made visible for gcc.

You can also run some ugly command to check some sort of cross compilation

```
gcc -march=native -E - < /dev/null
```

this command will fail, if it is cross compiler to different architecture, but it will not fail, if it is just for different operating system.

Comment: `gcc -march=native -E - < /dev/null` makes no sense and is absolutely not guaranteed to fail. Autoconf is trying to run a test binary of the target platform, if it is possible to run it, then "checking whether we are cross compiling..." will output **no**, so if Automake is able to run a.exe via wine, then it will output **no** for MinGW, even on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. #if defined(**GNUC**) is probably what you are looking for to get the compiler. If you want to see whether a particular target is used, then there might be another macro for the hardware. 
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html