# default value of __PTRDIFF_TYPE__

Tags: c

I see it is legal to use the variable `__PTRDIFF_TYPE__` with no header inclusion.

I tried to look for this variable name in `ISO/IEC 9899` but it does not appear. I expected to see its definition in the 7th part, C library.

Why is it legal ?

I am using the gcc under Linux/GNU.

Comment: Which compiler are you talking about?

Comment: oh, I forgot to mention the system -- linux/gnu, so gcc.

Comment: To see predefined macros from gcc (and clang), you can use the command: [`gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines)

Comment: @Cornstalks: interesting

Comment: That is not standard. And even if implemented, it is **not a variable**, not even a constant, but a macro! What's your problem using the standard type? Relying on such implementation-macros is a bad idea in general. I doubt it is legal for an application to use it. It clearly is not from the standard. Where did you get that impression from?

Comment: As requested by the OP I have closed this as a duplicate of the newer question that, they say, more precisely states what they want to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a predefined macro in gcc (a GNU C extension); see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html.

As for why this is legal: The standard reserves all names starting with two underscores (and all names starting with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter) for use by the implementation, so gcc could predefine `__whatever` and still follow the standard.

Comment: ah, you mean it's a GCC extension ?  I suspect it's used by other compilers.

Comment: @alinsoar: It is an extension to be used for the standard headers. Maybe that's easier than a bunch of `ifdef` to customize `ptrdiff_t` for each platform. As I wrote above, you must not use it in application code.

Comment: It is legal for an implementation to define that macro. It is not automatically granted to be used by an application. From the standard's view it definitively is not.

Comment: I suspect, the insertion of such type of variable/object macros are useful for gcc to compile on multiple platforms.  So, such a variable is a variable inserted in some ``ARCH.CONF`` file.

Comment: @alinsoar: I think that's what my comment says

Comment: Actually my real misunderstanding here is why it's necessary to define both the ``__PTRDIFF_TYPE__`` and in the same time ``ptrdiff_t``? Why only one of them isn't enough?  This is what I do not understand in all this bussiness.  Can you detail this in your answer ?