# youcompleteme and finding h files

Tags: vim, embedded, avr, avr-gcc, youcompleteme

I've got an embedded project I'm doing and I'd like to use Vim and YCM to do it.  I've got the following code as a quick prototype:

```
#include <avr/io.h>

#define USART_BAUDRATE 9600
#define BAUD_PRESCALE (((F_CPU/(USART_BAUDRATE*16UL)))-1)

int main(void){
 char recieved_byte;

 UCSR0B |= (1<<RXEN0)  | (1<<TXEN0);
 UCSR0C |= (1<<UCSZ00) | (1<<UCSZ01);
 UBRR0H  = (BAUD_PRESCALE >> 8);
 UBRR0L  = BAUD_PRESCALE;

    for(;;){
  // wait until a byte is ready to read
  while( ( UCSR0A & ( 1 << RXC0 ) ) == 0 ){}

  // grab the byte from the serial port
  recieved_byte = UDR0;

  // wait until the port is ready to be written to
  while( ( UCSR0A & ( 1 << UDRE0 ) ) == 0 ){}

  // write the byte to the serial port
  UDR0 = recieved_byte;
    }
    return 0;   /* never reached */
}
```

and I've got this for a `.ycm_extra_conf.py

```
import os
import ycm_core
from clang_helpers import PrepareClangFlags

# Set this to the absolute path to the folder (NOT the file!) containing the
# compile_commands.json file to use that instead of 'flags'. See here for
# more details: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html
# Most projects will NOT need to set this to anything; you can just change the
# 'flags' list of compilation flags. Notice that YCM itself uses that approach.
compilation_database_folder = ''

# These are the compilation flags that will be used in case there's no
# compilation database set.
flags = [
'-D__AVR_ATtiny167__',
# THIS IS IMPORTANT! Without a "-std=<something>" flag, clang won't know which
# language to use when compiling headers. So it will guess. Badly. So C++
# headers will be compiled as C headers. You don't want that so ALWAYS specify
# a "-std=<something>".
# For a C project, you would set this to something like 'c99' instead of
# 'c++11'.
'-std=c99',
# ...and the same thing goes for the magic -x option which specifies the
# language that the files to be compiled are written in. This is mostly
# relevant for c++ headers.
# For a C project, you would set this to 'c' instead of 'c++'.
'-isystem',
'/usr/avr/include/avr',
'/usr/avr/include/',
'-isystem',
'/usr/local/avr/include',
'/usr/local/avr/',
'-DF_CPU=16000000UL',
'-DARCH=ARCH_ATTINY',
'-DF_USB=16000000',
'-DBOARD=BOARD_NONE',
'-DFLASH_SIZE_BYTES=128000',
'-DBOOTLOADER_SEC_SIZE_BYTES=8192',
'-DUSB_DEVICE_ONLY',
'-DNO_STREAM_CALLBACKS',
'-DINTERRUPT_CONTROL_ENDPOINT',
'-DUSE_FLASH_DESCRIPTORS',
'-DUSE_STATIC_OPTIONS="(USB_DEVICE_OPT_FULLSPEED | USB_OPT_PLLCLKSRC)"',
'-DFIXED_CONTROL_ENDPOINT_SIZE=32',
'-DFIXED_NUM_CONFIGURATIONS=1',
'-DMPU9150',
'-Os',
'-funsigned-char',
'-fpack-struct',
'-fshort-enums',
'-Wall',
'-Wstrict-prototypes',
'-I',
'.',
'-I',
'./XMEGA/',
'-I', 'include',
'-I.',
# This path is for AVR gcc. 
]

if compilation_database_folder:
  database = ycm_core.CompilationDatabase( compilation_database_folder )
else:
  database = None


def DirectoryOfThisScript():
  return os.path.dirname( os.path.abspath( __file__ ) )


def MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute( flags, working_directory ):
  if not working_directory:
    return flags
  new_flags = []
  make_next_absolute = False
  path_flags = [ '-isystem', '-I', '-iquote', '--sysroot=' ]
  for flag in flags:
    new_flag = flag

    if make_next_absolute:
      make_next_absolute = False
      if not flag.startswith( '/' ):
        new_flag = os.path.join( working_directory, flag )

    for path_flag in path_flags:
      if flag == path_flag:
        make_next_absolute = True
        break

      if flag.startswith( path_flag ):
        path = flag[ len( path_flag ): ]
        new_flag = path_flag + os.path.join( working_directory, path )
        break

    if new_flag:
      new_flags.append( new_flag )
  return new_flags


def FlagsForFile( filename ):
  if database:
    # Bear in mind that compilation_info.compiler_flags_ does NOT return a
    # python list, but a "list-like" StringVec object
    compilation_info = database.GetCompilationInfoForFile( filename )
    final_flags = PrepareClangFlags(
        MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute(
            compilation_info.compiler_flags_,
            compilation_info.compiler_working_dir_ ),
        filename )

  else:
    relative_to = DirectoryOfThisScript()
    final_flags = MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute( flags, relative_to )

  return {
    'flags': final_flags,
    'do_cache': True
  }
```

`

The problem is that when editing the file, every single instance of an AVR register (which I thought was defined in `avr/io.h` and it's subsequent location was referenced in the `.ycm_extra_conf.py` file) is being flagged as an `undeclared identifier`.

I'm using Arch Linux and am programming an ATMega328p.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: pay attention to your flags. Example of one issue, you're doing `'-isystem', '/usr/local/avr/include', '/usr/local/avr/'`. Here you have two directories in sequence. Each include directory must be preceeded by the include flag, and generally you should use `-I`, not `-system` for everything. This is just one problem, there may be more.

Comment: Why not?  and I have to repeat myself for each one?

Comment: I have never seen/used multiple directories for a single include flag being used with compilers. So I'm not sure it works, I just know what has always worked for me.

Comment: `-DARCH=ARCH_ATTINY` looks wrong - the part is a ATMega not an ATTiny.  Are these macros from a different project?  You should fix that - it needs to match the actual build.

Comment: Very good, thank you.  This is very confusing in that , yes, there is a lot of documentation,but you don't know what you don't know.  I will look into that further.

Comment: Very good, thank you.  This is very confusing in that , yes, there is a lot of documentation,but you don't know what you don't know.  I will look into that further.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm struggling with it right now.

Comment: Yes...Cliffords advice was correct, but I had another issue...I left off the period in the ycm_extra_conf.py

Answer (score 0):

io.h includes conditional compilation to select specific AVR parts.  Your pre-processor macros list (`-D...` options) does not include `__AVR_ATmega328P__` so the code parser excludes all the necessary part specific declarations, just as the pre-processor would is the macro did not exist.

As well as you own project definitions, you should set any that are defined by the compiler or build system.

Comment: I see...Where are all these possible directives listed?  Where could I have found out on my own that __AVR_ATmega328P__ is a valid option for there?

Comment: @BrocolliRob : I looked in [io.h](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/io_8h_source.html), and observed the conditional compilation - it is not VIM/YCM specific.  You can see the command-line defined macros for your build simply by observing the build log.  For GCC internally pre-defined macros can be dumped as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines) - some are determined by other compiler options, so include all used by your project to get an accurate list.