# How to dump a complete list of compiler attributes in Rust?

Tags: rust, preprocessor

While some compiler attributes are [documented here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#conditional-compilation), is it possible to get a complete list of all attributes from Rust, including those defined by the build environment? Something similar to [`gcc -dM -E`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rustc -W help` will give you a list of rustc lint checks and their defaults, but it doesn't contain conditional compilation attributes; the link you referenced appears to provide their comprehensive list, but if you're not sure it is up to date, you can check [the source](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/91f057de35066d0a34102bd0673b56684509b93d/src/librustc/session/config.rs#L942).