# How can I quickly determine which macros my code uses?

Tags: c, macros, static-analysis, dead-code

I have cut out a piece of code out of a larger (C) project. The code has many many macros defined, in many place - some of them are only used by the original, larger codebase, and not used by the part of the code I cut out.

I want to quickly determine which of these macros are in actual use, and which aren't (so that I can remove those that aren't). I don't care whether the code paths which uses them get taken or not (i.e. `if (1+1 == 3) { MY_MACRO(a,b,c); }` is a use as far as I'm concerned.

What's a good way to do this? The best I could think of is preprocess everything with -E and look for source position comments which mention the macro somehow.

**Notes:**

- If you have a solution that also lists the functions in use, that's fine too.
- I only directly call certain functions in the code I cut out of the project. If your solution can limit the macros listed to those in functions which many actually get called from the entry-points, that's even better
- My code compiles and runs (and you can assume gprof output if that helps)
- Just commenting out all macros, while obviously feasible, is a hassle; so I want a solution which does not require my doing that.
- Code excluded by the preprocessor is unused; but if you have a solution which does not observe this restriction, that's still better than nothing.
- I don't want to ["dump the list of preprocessor defines"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334) - but rather those defines *that are in use*.

Comment: Comment out all `#define` directives and rebuild. Check which symbols are complained about.

Comment: Sidenote: Since your code compiles, remember to compare binaries before and after macro removal. You may accidentally remove macro which is used in conditional compilation, and get no warnings or errors.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: See edit. I want to be lazier than that.

Comment: What about code excluded by preprocessor? Should macro `FOO` be listed if it is excluded by, say, `#ifdef DEBUG`?

Comment: @deniss: Unused. But see edit.

Comment: One could probably produce a list of all identifiers which are followed by optional whitespace and then a round bracket with grep or similar. That should be a list of all function and macro definitions and calls. Compare those with a list of symbols produced by `objdump` or `nm`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCC dump preprocessor defines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines)

Comment: @AndrewHenle Interesting link; although I think the OP wants not the definitions (there are plenty) but only the few *uses* of some of the definitions.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Actually, this question is about how to _not_ get the entire dump of preprocessor defines.

Answer (score 3):

There exists `clang` tool named [pp-trace](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/pp-trace.html). It outputs every preprocessor invocation with its parameters.

You are interested in `MacroExpands` event, it looks like so in `pp-trace` output:

```
...

- Callback: MacroExpands
  MacroNameTok: X_IMPL
  MacroDirective: MD_Define
  Range: [(nonfile), (nonfile)]
  Args: [a <plus> y, b]

...
```

Extracting `MacroNameTok` from `MacroExpands` block should do the trick for you.

Comment: deniss, is that available in clang-3.8? I'm having trouble locating it on my Kubuntu 16.04 distribution.

Comment: @einpoklum, it should be. Unfortunately, I only ever built it from sources, so unsure if it is redistributed as binary.

Comment: Well, just so you know: [it's missing from *buntu 16.04 and nobody knows why.](http://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/1319419?noredirect=1).