# Predefined macro to distinguish arm-none-eabi-gcc from gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, macros, arm

I am building my own library which is supposed to work both on an arm mbed and on linux platforms. If the target is ARM mbed, then the library needs to be cross-compiled with `arm-none-eabi-gcc` while if the target platform is linux, the library needs to be compiled with `gcc`. Is there a predefined compiler macro that will allow me to determine which compiler was invoked to compile the library? Note that Raspberry Pi which 
has an ARM CPU also needs to be supported so I cannot use any arch macros.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCC dump preprocessor defines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines)

Comment: I already tried the suggestions in this thread, but there are a lot of macros and it takes ages to go through all of them one by one.

Comment: Try comparing the lists generated by the two compiler using some `diff`. Or look here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-specific-Predefined-Macros.html#System-specific-Predefined-Macros

Comment: already tried `diff` too: the output is twice as long... The link however helped me find a possible answer. Seems like `__unix__` can work. Thanks!

Comment: You're doing it bass-ackwards, I think. You should either have a simple `configure` script (run before `make`) to select the target architecture; or have a Makefile with the different targets (so `make mbed` compiles ARM mbed version, `make linux` a generic Linux version, `make pi` for Raspberry Pi, and so on); with those defining some preprocessor macros your code can use if there are code-level differences.

Comment: If the output with diff is twice as long, you are doing it wrong...

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the comments and this link: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-specific-Predefined-Macros.html#System-specific-Predefined-Macros, the macro `__unix__` will be defined by `gcc` but not by `arm-none-eabi-gcc`. If anyone has a better answer, please post it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [ARM Compiler Toolchain Reference](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0491/i/Compiler-specific-Features/Predefined-macros), macro `__arm__` is always defined for the ARM compiler `arm-none-eabi-gcc`.