# whats happens when using #define with no replacement string?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

When trying to debug my code, I marked a few `printf` with this:

```
#if debug
    printf(...);
#endif
```

And at the start of the file, I mistakenly wrote `#define debug` instead of `#define debug 1`

gcc threw the following error:

> error: #if with no expression

Now I have 2 options:

1. changing the define into `#define debug 1`
2. changing the if into `#ifdef debug`

I know that upon seeing `#define debug 1` the PP will replace each `debug` in my code to `1` and that's why `#if debug` in my code didn't work - the compiler sees no expression...

My question is, when I use `#ifdef debug` - what happens? I figure `debug` is saved somewhere and checked, but where and how?

Comment: The "where" could be as simple as a list of all macros in the current [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)), and the "how" (in regards to checking with `#ifdef`) is simply looking for the macro in the list.

Comment: How can I locate and print this macro list?

Comment: @CIsForCookies for `gcc`, [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines) (of course, instead of `/dev/null`, feed it your actual source file)

Comment: That depends on the compiler you're using. It might have options to give you that list. Or it might not have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually quite simple: `#define debug` **does** define `debug` to be empty. It is still *defined*. An empty macro is different from one that doesn't exist. `#undef debug` would remove the macro.

`#ifdef` doesn't care about the value. It only checks whether the macro is defined to whatever. If you don't care about the value, always use `#ifdef`.

Comment: I'm trying to check it against __#define debug ""__ but that throws an error:  token """" is not valid in preprocessor expressions

Comment: @CIsForCookies Don't confuse preprocessor syntax with C syntax. A preprocessor token can of course contain `""`, for the preprocessor, this are just two characters (it's NOT the same as *empty*). -- `#define debug ""` is perfectly valid.

Comment: So the only way to replace a string with empty string for the PP will be to leave it as I defined?

Comment: @CIsForCookies I don't understand what you're asking in this last comment. If you want your macro to expand to an *empty string constant*, define it as `""`. If you want your macro to be empty (so the expansion will contain nothing at all), define it without a value.

Answer (score 3):

The relevant syntax for the `#define` preprocessing directive is spelled out in [§6.10 ¶1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10p1) (C11 Draft Standard):

> **# define** *identifier replacement-list new-line*
>   ...
>   *replacement-list: pp-tokens<sub>opt</sub>*

The semantics of the `#define` directive are found in [§6.10.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3p9):

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> **# define** *identifier replacement-list new-line*
>
> defines an *object-like macro* that causes each subsequent instance of
>   the macro name to be replaced by the replacement list of
>   preprocessing tokens that constitute the remainder of the directive.
>   The replacement list is then rescanned for more macro names as
>   specified below.

Note that a replacement-list is *optionally* composed of preprocessing tokens, and thus may be empty. So, to consider a [footnoted example from the Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10p8):

```
#define EMPTY
```

Since, according to [§6.10.3 ¶7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3p7):

> The identifier immediately following the **define** is called the *macro
>   name*. There is one name space for macro names.

the macro name `EMPTY` has been defined, and exists in the namespace for macro names. Each subsequent instance of `EMPTY` will be replaced by no preprocessing tokens.