# How to interpret #-prefixed lines in C preprocessor output?

Tags: c-preprocessor

The following is the code of hello.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (void)
{
  printf ("Hello, world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I used the command `gcc -E hello.c` to preprocess it, and got the following output:

```
# 1 "hello.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "hello.c"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 1 3 4
# 27 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/features.h" 1 3 4
# 375 "/usr/include/features.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h" 1 3 4
# 392 "/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/bits/wordsize.h" 1 3 4
# 393 "/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h" 2 3 4
# 376 "/usr/include/features.h" 2 3 4
# 399 "/usr/include/features.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h" 1 3 4
# 10 "/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/gnu/stubs-64.h" 1 3 4
# 11 "/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h" 2 3 4
# 400 "/usr/include/features.h" 2 3 4
# 28 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 2 3 4





# 1 "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include/stddef.h" 1 3 4
# 212 "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include/stddef.h" 3 4
typedef long unsigned int size_t;
# 34 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 2 3 4

# 1 "/usr/include/bits/types.h" 1 3 4
# 27 "/usr/include/bits/types.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/bits/wordsize.h" 1 3 4
# 28 "/usr/include/bits/types.h" 2 3 4


typedef unsigned char __u_char;
typedef unsigned short int __u_short;
typedef unsigned int __u_int;
typedef unsigned long int __u_long;


typedef signed char __int8_t;
typedef unsigned char __uint8_t;
typedef signed short int __int16_t;
typedef unsigned short int __uint16_t;
typedef signed int __int32_t;
typedef unsigned int __uint32_t;

typedef signed long int __int64_t;
typedef unsigned long int __uint64_t;
////I omitted a lot in the following.
```

I know these information can be used for debugging symbols. But I want to know the meaning of each FIELD. However, if you are able to answer the following ones, your answer will also be accepted.

1. What does `# 1 "<built-in>" and # 1 "<command-line>"`mean? Why it gave me message of built-in and command-line, which are totally not relevant?
2. What does `#1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4` mean? What is the meaning of 1 3 4?

Thanks. Please note that I know preprocessor will include the header files. I want to know the meaning of each FIELD of the preprocessed output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fields of the preprocessor output are documented in [9 Preprocessor Output](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html)
of the GNU cpp manual.

The fields are:

```
# linenum filename [flags]
...
```

Such a line means that *what follows it* (`...`) originated at line
number `linenum` in file `filename`. The optional `flags` are:-

> ‘1’
>
> This indicates the start of a new file.
>
> ‘2’
>
> This indicates returning to a file (after having included another file).
>
> ‘3’
>
> This indicates that the following text comes from a system header file, so certain warnings should be suppressed.
>
> ‘4’
>
> This indicates that the following text should be treated as being wrapped in an implicit extern "C" block.

You see that nesting arises from `#include` directives, e.g.

```
# 1 "hello.c"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 1 3 4
# 27 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/features.h" 1 3 4
# 375 "/usr/include/features.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h" 1 3 4
...
```

tells us:

- At line #1 of `"hello.c"` start a new file `"/usr/include/stdio.h"`,
- at line #27 of which start another new file `"/usr/include/features.h"`
- at line #375 of which start another new file `"/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h"`
- ...

It's not easy reading.

The special "filenames" `<built-in>` and `<command-line>` will always crop up
in a context resembling:-

```
# 1 "hello.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "hello.c"
```

at the top of the preprocessed output for any file. Details may vary with GCC version.

As you'd guess, `<built-in>` and `<command-line>` are not real files. They
are non-file sources of preprocessor tokens that need to be represented somehow
in the output format, so they are treated *as if* they were files. Call them *pseudo-files*.

`<built-in>` is the pseudo-file that contains the compiler's built-in macro
definitions. For the way to see the contents of this pseudo-file, browse to
[GCC dump preprocessor defines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2224334/1362568).

`<command-line>` is of course the preprocessor (usually GCC) commandline,
considered as a source of macro definitions (and possibly un-definitions), e.g.

```
gcc ... -DFOO=1 -UBAR ...
```

So your example:

```
# 1 "hello.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "hello.c"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 1 3 4
...
```

represents this process:

- Start reading `hello.c`, and then
- immediately read the built-in macros pseudo-file, and then
- immediately read the commandline pseudo-file, and then
- immediately read the pre-defined macros file `/usr/include/stdc-predef.h`
  *as if* it was pre-included on the commandline by `-include /usr/include/stdc-predef.h`, and then
- resume and finish reading the commandline pseudo-file, and then
- resume reading `hello.c`, and then
- start reading `/usr/include/stdio.h`
  ...

Comment: Excellent answer!  Surely I will learn a lot from it. Thanks!