# Does C preprocessor for OSX detection work on Mojave?

Tags: c, macos, macos-mojave

Is the C preprocessor for Mac OSX not working with Mojave correctly, or am I making some dumb mistake? The code below compiles but will not print "test" to the console.

According to https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/ and multiple Stack Overflow posts I have looked at `__APPLE__` *should* do the trick. I've also tried `__MACH__` and using `__APPLE__ && __MACH__` but this does not work either.

I'm compiling in terminal via gcc.

Is it possible that these don't work with the newest version of OSX as it was only released a few weeks ago? I never had this problem until I updated to Mojave.

I've also tried calling a function in place of `printf("test");` but the results are the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{  
    #ifdef __APPLE__
      printf("test");
    #endif

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're using only a single underscore. Does \_\_APPLE\_\_ or \_\_MACH\_\_ work?

Comment: No, sorry, In my real code I'm using the double underscore, just a typo in here. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Can you post the output of `gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null` ? see [gcc-dump-preprocesor-defines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines).

Comment: `#define __APPLE__ 1` is missing from it, so that's clearly why it isn't working. I am going to reinstall gcc and see if it comes back.

Comment: reinstalling fixed this. May have corrupted from OS update, I had to reinstall xCode command line tools when i first upgraded too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling GCC seems to have resolved the issue. `#define __APPLE__ 1` was missing from gcc when I ran `gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null` in terminal. It has returned upon reinstall. Possible corruption from upgrading.