# Best way to convert #defines into Lua global variables?

Tags: lua

I'm trying to read and detect all #define preprocessors in a
C header file (`glew.h`) so I can convert them to Lua global variables.

For example, `#define GL_RGB 0x1908` will be detected and run as the following code so it can be registered as a global variable in Lua.

```
lua_pushnumber(L, 0x1908);
lua_setglobal(L, "GL_RGB");
```

Is this a good idea? Or would it be too slow to process the header file whenever the app starts?

All I want is to be able to use all the `#defines`in Lua.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines