# Is it possible to check preprocessor defines with string?

Tags: c++, preprocessor

I wonder if it is possible to check if the preprocessor defined variable exists or not using string.

For example,

```
#define TARGET_ANDROID

if (checkIfDefineExists("TARGET_ANDROID"))
{
    cout << "It is defined\n";
}
```

Then the result should print `It is defined`.

As far as I know it is not possible, but I wonder if there's any work around to it.

Comment: Are you looking for `#ifdef TARGET_ANDROID` or `#if defiined(TARGET_ANDROID)`?  The preprocessor _changes the program text_ before the front end even sees the code.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm No I'm not looking for a way to check it by comparing with a string.

Comment: How are you getting the string? Is it available during compile time like your example code or is it only available during run time?

Comment: @ZackLee `#define` are consumed by the preprocessor. This means that those defines are done when the program is ready to be compiled. What you can do is to use `#ifdef` to define variables or strings to be read in your program

Comment: @taskinoor It is only available during run time.

Comment: @ZackLee then you can't check it. If you describe what you are trying to achieve really then someone may be able to provide an alternate approach.

Comment: No, this is not possible as described. Can you give more details about your high level goal?

Comment: That's exactly for what the preprocessor command `#ifdef`is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I know it is not possible

Correct.

> but I wonder if there's any work around to it.

No. But if your goal is to find out for what target your program was compiled, you can do:

```
#if defined(TARGET_ANDROID)
#  define TARGET "ANDROID"
#elif defined(TARGET_IOS)
#  define TARGET "IOS"
#endif

if (checkIfTargetIs("ANDROID")) {
    cout << "It is ANDROID\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't even make sense to ask whether it is possible, because "it" has not been defined.

```
#define TARGET_ANDROID
if 
#undef TARGET_ANDROID
 (
#define TARGET_ANDROID
  checkIfDefineExists
#undef TARGET_ANDROID
   (
#define TARGET_ANDROID
     "TARGET_ANDROID"
#undef TARGET_ANDROID
    )
#define TARGET_ANDROID
  )
#undef TARGET_ANDROID
{ 
cout << "It is defined\n";
}
```

What do you want your program to print, and why?

Comment: It's complicated to explain but I'm trying to convert #defines to Lua global variables. It is related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56268080/best-way-to-convert-defines-into-lua-global-variables

Comment: You are trying to convert `#define`s that are in effect *where exactly*?