# Is there an easy way to analyse the header files and get a resulting list of all #defines?

Tags: c++, c

Sorry for the what I am sure is a basic question, but I must not be using the right terms when searching for an answer with code that has hundreds of header files. Simply searching the files for `#define` statements is tedious. Is there an easy way in Visual Studio or VSCode to just have it step through the files and give me a list of all values literals and their values?

Comment: This is not a simple question. As an example, consider `#ifdef FOO #define BAR FOO #else #define FOO 42`. How `FOO` is defined depends on `BAR`. Practically, this means you can't analyze headers in isolation, only Translation Units. And that means you get many dependencies on header guards (`#ifndef FOO_H_INCLUDED_ #define FOO_H_INCLUDED_ ... #endif // FOO_H_INCLUDED_`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GCC dump preprocessor defines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you can get is to use the [`/P`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/p-preprocess-to-a-file?view=vs-2019) compiler switch to dump the preprocessed output to a file. It's going to be pretty huge, but it shows you precisely what the compiler is working with, and you can do a text search in the output file to find what you're looking for.

Comment: IMO you could run diff against the *cpp and output and this would give you some insight