# where is __OBJC2__?

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

from https://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/objc4/.
`__OBJC2__` is still exist in objc4-787.1, but missing in objc4-818.2, so where is it?

`__OBJC2__` in objc4-787.1

```
// Define __OBJC2__ for the benefit of our asm files.
#ifndef __OBJC2__
#   if TARGET_OS_OSX  &&  !TARGET_OS_IOSMAC  &&  __i386__
        // old ABI
#   else
#       define __OBJC2__ 1
#   endif
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* the compiler sets that flag.

The following program shows that the flag is set, even though it does not include any Objective-C headers. The only giveaway is that the file is a `.m` thus my conclusion.

```
// main.m
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  printf( "Hallo world\n" );
  printf( "Definition %d\n", __OBJC2__ );
}
```

Compile with

```
cc main.m
```

Compiler

```
cc --version
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
```

Output

```
Hallo world
Definition 1
```

**EDIT**

Based on [GCC dump preprocessor defines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines) I was able to verify this. Just create an empty `.m` file and run

```
cc -dM -E empty.m
```

or better run

```
cc -dM -E empty.m | grep OBJ
```

and you will see the definition. Also compare to a C file e.g.

```
cc -dM -E empty.c | grep OBJ
```

where it is NOT defined.