# Is there any macro defined when compiling with --coverage option?

Tags: c++, c, gcov

As mentioned by the title, I would like to achieve something like this:

```c
void my_exit(int status)
{
#ifdef _GCOV
   __gcov_flush();
#endif
   _exit(status);
}
```

But I do not know if there is a `_GCOV`（or something similar） defined when compiling with `--coverage`. Any idea will be appreciated!

Comment: Also see: [GCC dump preprocessor defines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2224334/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be:

```
$ true | gcc -E - -dM > no-coverage.h
$ true | gcc -E - -dM --coverage > coverage.h
$ diff no-coverage.h coverage.h
```

Comment: I see, i probably need to define my own macro

Answer (score 3):

Since there appears to not be a pre-defined macro, as per o11c's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67428950/2079303), a simple solution is to define it yourself:

```
gcc --coverage -D GCOV
```