# How can I make compiler version specific ifdef?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, arduino-c++

I've got the problem that my program will compile with g++10.2 and c++11 activated through cmake. but it will not compile with arduino dues arm-none-eabi-g++.exe compiler which also has c++11. The failure occurs because of one line that needs to be added for the arm compiler, but when I add that line to g++10.2 it won't compile.

So I need an `#ifdef` or some alternative to activate and deactivate the line specific for the compiler.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines to find predefined macros for both of your compilers. You can then use one that is defined differently between the two compilers.

Comment: try to use ```__arm__```, ```__aarch64__``` or ```__ARM_ARCH``` macro

Answer (score 0):

Like Deumaudit said in the comments:

> Try to use `__arm__`, `__aarch64__` or `__ARM_ARCH` macro

You'll probably be ok if you use `#ifdef __arm__` or even `#if defined(__arm__) || defined(__aarch64__)`

If you're planning to add more supported platforms to your program, it might be a good idea to define some macros when building for a specific platform. I have my own `_MY_APP_ARM` macro defined in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR} MATCHES "arm")
    add_definitions(-D_MY_APP_ARM)
endif()
```

Which I can then use as `#ifdef _MY_APP_ARM`