# Predefined macro to determine if running on a Raspberry?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, arm, c-preprocessor

I'm maintaining an application that runs on GNU/Linux (x86, x86_64), Windows (x86, x86_64), Bionic/Android (armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64) and also on Raspberry Pi (armhf). Since Raspberry OS is actually a modified version of GNU/Linux Debian, i can [determine](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/) if i'm running linux (`__linux__`) on ARM (`__arm__`), but i can't discern if it's hard-float or not. (Yes, this may be an XY Problem.)

I need a way to pinpoint raspberry as some parts of the code are **not** to be implemented on Android. Yes, i could use `-DRASPBERRY` at compile time but was wondering if the compiler already does that for me. Preferably a standard macro instead of a compiler-specific one, but i'm cross-compiling on linux with gcc.

I'm considering `__ARM_FP`, but not sure.

This software runs on models 2 and up, any tips are appreciated.

**Edit 1**

To determine this, i've been using the output of the native gcc on linux x86_64, the 4 NDK variants and a mingw crross-compiler for x86. These caught my attention:

`__ARM_ARCH` is on all
`__ARM_32BIT_STATE` and `__ARM_64BIT_STATE` may be useful
`__ARM_EABI__` and `__ARMEL__` seem to only appear in Android's `armeabi-v7a` and the gcc in Raspbian, so may be good candidates
`__ARM_FP` has a different value on all of them, which may also be useful once i figure out what it means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, according to [Arm C Language Extensions](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101028/latest)

> 5.5.1 Hardware floating point
> __ARM_FP is set if hardware floating-point is available.

...and proceeds to enumerate the possible valid values as `0x04`, `0x6`, `0xC` and `0xE`.

The NDK sets `0xC` for `armeabi-v7a` and `0xE` for `arm64-v8a` and i got a bit confused because the gcc compiler in Raspberry OS sets it to `12`... which is `0x0C`.

Answer (score 4):

Approach the problem generally. How do you determine what flags are available? Use [GCC dump preprocessor defines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines) .

> i can't discern if it's hard-float or not.

That's trivial:

- list all compiler macros with hard float
- list all compiler macros without hard float
- show the difference

For exmaple: I take `arm-none-eabi-gcc` and `cortex-m7` has hardware float support. I do:

```
$ get() { arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m7 -dM -E - < /dev/null "$@" | sort; }
$ diff <(get -mfloat-abi=soft) <(get -mfloat-abi=hard)
26c26,27
< #define __ARM_PCS 1
---
> #define __ARM_FP 14
> #define __ARM_PCS_VFP 1
132a134,139
> #define __FP_FAST_FMA 1
> #define __FP_FAST_FMAF 1
> #define __FP_FAST_FMAF32 1
> #define __FP_FAST_FMAF32x 1
> #define __FP_FAST_FMAF64 1
> #define __FP_FAST_FMAL 1
153,154c160,161
< #define __GCC_IEC_559 0
< #define __GCC_IEC_559_COMPLEX 0
---
> #define __GCC_IEC_559 2
> #define __GCC_IEC_559_COMPLEX 2
299d305
< #define __SOFTFP__ 1
```

`__SOFTFP__` might be super interesting for you (**when using that particular compiler**).

> Predefined macro to determine if running on a Raspberry?

Well, you can't know what your code will be running on, only the architecture it is *compiled* for. Seeing the output of:

```
diff <(ssh myraspberry gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null | sort) <(gcc -dM -E - </dev/null | sort)
```

Those macros might sound interesting:

```
< #define __ARM_32BIT_STATE 1
< #define __ARM_ARCH 6
< #define __ARM_ARCH_6__ 1
< #define __ARM_ARCH_ISA_ARM 1
< #define __ARM_ARCH_ISA_THUMB 1
< #define __ARM_EABI__ 1
< #define __ARM_FEATURE_CLZ 1
< #define __ARM_FEATURE_COPROC 15
< #define __ARM_FEATURE_DSP 1
< #define __ARM_FEATURE_LDREX 4
< #define __ARM_FEATURE_QBIT 1
< #define __ARM_FEATURE_SAT 1
< #define __ARM_FEATURE_SIMD32 1
< #define __ARM_FEATURE_UNALIGNED 1
< #define __ARM_FP 12
< #define __ARM_PCS_VFP 1
```

Comment: I have been dumping the preprocessor defines already. Does a cross-compiler generate the same defines as a native compiler in this regard?