GCC Compile-time switch for floating point support?
I am working on some programs for two different riscv processors. One is IMC, and the other is IMFC. I'd like to add a compile switch to my program to block out floating point code for the IMC target and leave it intact for the IMFC one. Ideally I'd get something that looks like this pseudo-code
#if RISCV_FLOATING_POINT_SUPPORTED // Floating point maths #endif // Non floating point maths 
I've been doing some digging but I cannot find this switch in any of the online documentation. I see lots of documentation for the compile options (-march for example) but that doesn't really help me (or if it does I'm not sure how to parse that out at compile time). I am using GCC version 11.2. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!
EDIT: The two responses to this post have helped greatly already. I ran echo | gcc -dM -E -march=rv32imfc - and rv32imc and compared the two outputs. I found a couple of deltas that should allow me to do what I want. Thanks for the input folks!

Wouldn't it be easier to test for two conditions, e.g. along the lines of if defined(RISCV) && defined (has_FP) ?

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines for a way to figure it out yourself.

@MSalters Yes ideally I'd have a check for both of those, but in this environment it's highly unlikely this code will be compiled for a non-RISCV target. The real substance is finding a way to check if the compile option for an FPU being present exists...
Thanks for the link to that other post! Always looking to learn new things. I'll poke around with GCC and see if there's anything that'll work for me.

Basically there are two things to consider: ABI and instruction presence.
Here are three possible options:

Hard float (F/D/Q extensions present).

$ riscv64-linux-gnu-gcc -E -dM -c test.c
#define __riscv_float_abi_double 1
#define __riscv_d 2000000
#define __riscv_f 2000000
...

My compiler is defaulted to gc level extensions, so here we have double and float instruction set support, and hard-float ABI.

Hard float instructions, but soft-float ABI

$ riscv64-linux-gnu-gcc -E -dM -c test.c -mabi=lp64
#define __riscv_float_abi_soft 1
#define __riscv_d 2000000
#define __riscv_f 2000000
...

The compiler assumes instructions are supported or emulated by firmware, and will use them as necessary, but uses soft-float ABI to pass float arguments and results along.

No floating point instructions, soft float ABI

$ riscv64-linux-gnu-gcc -E -dM -c test.c -mabi=lp64 -march=rv64i
#define __riscv_float_abi_soft 1
...

It is assumed processor supports no FP instructions; soft-float ABI and soft float library support is used for floating point code.

This was a good answer! The link from the comment on the original post helped by giving context to those commands you're running, but the idea of checking these defines should work. Thanks!!
